# Mongoose nested ObjectId Array validation Dto

Tags: javascript, mongodb, validation, mongoose, dto

I have a Dto which looks like this:

```js
import { Type } from "class-transformer";
import { ArrayMinSize, IsArray, ValidateNested} from "class-validator";
import { ObjectId } from "mongoose";

export class MongoIdDto {
    @IsArray()
    @ValidateNested({each: true})
    @ArrayMinSize(1)
    @Type(() => ObjectId)
    ids: ObjectId[]
}
```

But this throws me an error:
`'ObjectId' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.`

How does this error occur?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a common import mistake:

ObjectId can be imported from mongoose and from mongoDB.

The mongoose import is a Type

The mongodb import is a class representation of the bson ObjectId Type

So to fix this issue change your import to:
`import { ObjectId } from "mongodb";`

But actually there is an option to validate MongoIds with this:

```js
export class MongoIdArrayDto {
    @IsMongoId({each: true})
    @ArrayMinSize(1)
    ids: ObjectId[]
}
```